# Theta V wifi api inconsitency

Tags: android, android-wifi, androidhttpclient, theta360

I'm implementing some functionality using the Ricoh Theta V device. It is the most basic functionality for the device that I can think of but using the api is so inconsistent, and the device keeps going off after a few minutes.

I just want to take a picture, save to the Android device. That's it.

Here's what I'm doing:

- Connect to the Theta Device over WiFi (Direct Mode)
- Use HttpAsyncClient to make a post request to the device (/osc/commands/execute)

Json for Post

```
{
"name": "camera.setOptions",
"parameters": {
  "options": {
  "fileFormat": {
    "type": "jpeg",
    "width": 2048,
    "height": 1024
  }
 }
}
}
```

- At the point above it times out or I get this message :

Error Message

```
{"error":{"code":"invalidParameterValue","message":"Any input parameter or option name is recognized, but its value is invalid."},"name":"camera.setOptions","state":"error"}
```

- When I do call take picture command directly it sometimes works, but I need the image to be less than 2048x2048 so that I can display it using panoramaGL.

I've tried the code from the "plugin" by importing the sample app as a library and using the HttpConnector to execute commands but the same problem occurs. It works once every 10-20 times, and then would fail the rest of the day after that.

Does anyone have any other resources, or a comprehensive overview on using this device in an Android application. Any resources besides the [official api overview](https://developers.theta360.com/en/docs/) because that's not helping at all.

I went through the forum already and no one is talking about the connection timeout issues, so I don't know if the device is faulty, or if this is normal behaviour that everyone has just accepted.

**Edit 1:** I also have a post on the Forums, and have posted two new updates. The replies still has to be approved before it's visible to public but it can be tracked [here](https://community.theta360.guide/t/wifi-requests-always-times-out-on-android/3504).

Answer (score 2):

In the v2.1 sample in the SDK there's a method called forceConnectToWifi(). I copied this over and called it in the onCreate of my capture activity and it made all the timeout problems go away.

You can see the full thread where I solved it [here](https://community.theta360.guide/t/wifi-requests-always-times-out-on-android/3504/6).